# How to get address,city name from longitude and latitude in iphone

Tags: iphone, latitude-longitude, street-address

How to get location details from a longitude/latitude value? Is there anyone who can help me with this situation.

Comment: please use a proper question format!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CLGeocoder to get the details from latitude and longitude.

Check out the [CLGeoCoder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at a MaxMind GeoIP API available for many languages: 
[Here](http://www.maxmind.com/app/c)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the google maps apis reverse geocoding functionality.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

you would make a request like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true
```

and receive a json encoded object containing a guess on the address (including city of course)

Answer (score 0):

This is called 'reverse geocoding', see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html